# Is there a simpler way to extract the last value of a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

So I was tasked to make a function using python, that returns how many values there is in a dictionary that ONLY contains lists. An example of such a dictionary would be:

```
animals = { 'a': ['alpaca','ardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati']}
```

The values inside the list also count towards the total values returned from the function, which means that it has to return 4. This is the function I made:

```
def how_many(aDict):
'''
aDict: A dictionary, where all the values are lists.

returns: int, how many values are in the dictionary.
'''
numValues = 0;
while aDict != {}:
    tupKeyValue = aDict.popitem();
    List = tupKeyValue[1];
    numValues += len(List);

return numValues;
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to pop the last value of a dictionary without popitem() which extracts the key-value pair. Just trying to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using the dictionaries keys maybe you could just use [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20values#dict.values) along with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum):

```
def how_many(d):
    return sum(len(v) for v in d.values())

animals = {'a': ['alpaca', 'ardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati']}
print(how_many(animals))
```

**Output:**

```
4
```